# Google Sheet Auto Select Drop Down First Item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible for a Google Sheet dropdown, to auto select the first item in the list onChange / onEdit?

I'm unable to complete this directly on the sheet (I could be missing something), and I don't know enough about the Google Sheep App Script environment to know if it's possible.

I'm assuming that using Google App Script, this could be done.

I have setup this demo sheet, with everything working (other than what I'm after ;-)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzRT8rikVUfpZVOmugebB2yVHdLv_60K_Jwvxi6fX0U/edit?usp=sharing

What I would really like, When a "Tool" is changed/selected, I would like the "Colors" dropdown to select the first item in the list.

So if you select "Pencil", "Blue" would be auto selected into the cel.  At the moment, the cel stays blank, until the user selects something.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the dropdown list of the cells "B5:B10" and the dropdown list of the column "C" is updated, you want to set the 2nd value of the updated dropdown list.
- For example, when the dropdown list of the cells "B5" is set to "Pencil", you want to set the dropdown list of the cells "C5" to "Blue".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to run the script using the OnEdit trigger of the simple trigger. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your sample Spreadsheet. And, please change the dropdown list of the column "B". By this, the script is run by the OnEdit trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.columnStart != 2 || range.rowStart < 5 || range.rowEnd > 10) return;
  const r = range.offset(0, 1);
  const value = [...new Set(r.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())].filter(e => e != "--")[0];
  r.setValue(value);
}
```

- In this sample, when the script is run, the range of the updated data validation rule is retrieved from the column "C", and retrieve the 2nd value of the dropdown list from the range.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, from your sample Spreadsheet, when the dropdown list of cells "B5:B10" are changed, the script is run. So when you want to expand this range, please modify above script.
- This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. When you change the sample Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidation)

Comment: Wow, thank you.  This works as expected.  
I had started following a few YT tutorials to learn some more Google App Scripting.  But it would have taken me a long time to actually solve this.  Thank you.

Comment: @James Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.